# R does not identify columns as numeric

Tags: r

A couple of months ago I started analysing my data, which worked fine. Now R does not recognize some of the columns as numeric anymore. I tried changing them to numeric manually, but ended up with NAs. Now I changed the empty rows to hold a 0 and that helped getting two more columns be numeric, but I still end up with some handled as characters.

```
Ben_sichel <- read.csv2("neu.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ",", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)[129:1859, ]
```

This is what I end up with:

```
'data.frame':   1731 obs. of  41 variables:
....
 $ SFRB     : num  0 0 2.2 20.8 0 20.9 15.2 0 16.4 0 ...
 $ SFRD     : num  0 0 1.2 11.7 0 5.7 7.7 0 4.4 0 ...
 $ ABW      : num  0 0 65 60 0 60 75 0 70 0 ...
....
 $ SAD      : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
 $ SPP      : chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
....
 $ AL       : chr  "0" "154,8" "54,0" "60,7" ...
 $ AB       : chr  "53,1" "72,6" "61,2" "57,8" ...
 $ AD       : num  12.6 43.5 6.1 15.6 4.2 12.7 17.1 13.6 10.1 10.7 ...
 $ AG       : num  177.9 481.2 16.3 42.8 0.8 ...
```

All of them are supposed to be numeric. And I can't find a solution, why they no longer numeric. I hope I made my question clear. I'm a bit new to R and not native english speaker.

Comment: You need to identify the problem entries in those columns. Since you haven't given a [mcve] we can do no more than guess.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your file is ***semicolon-separated*** and both commas and dots exist. You need to specify the ***decimal mark*** and ***grouping mark***. The `readr` package can deal with it.

**Scenario 1:** Decimal mark is comma(`,`) and grouping mark is dot(`.`)

```
readr::read_csv2("foo.csv") # all settings are default.
```

**Scenario 2:** Decimal mark is dot(`.`) and grouping mark is comma(`,`)

```
readr::read_delim("foo.csv",
                  delim = ";",
                  trim_ws = TRUE,
                  locale = locale(decimal_mark = "."))
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I found the problem, there were some - instead of just empty cells. So after removing them all needed colums are now numeric. Still, no plan why it worked in the first place...